# TYPO3 Remove/Exclude news-basic.css from Extension News

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

Im working with the News(news) Extension for TYPO3 v. 6.1 Fluid/Extbase.
it's working fine, but it's using the extension css file news-basic.css, how can I tell the extension that I don't want to use that Css file but I want to use my own main.css, that I allready is including.

I have read that it can be excluded, but I can't find anywhere to do that.

The issue is that some of the style in the css is making some issues in my main css.
Its a funny comment: "."; tag, but I don't need the extensions css file at all.

Can someone guide me to a solution, how to exclude the EXT News added news-basic.css file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a constant for this:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.cssFile = EXT:news/Resources/Public/Css/news-basic.css
```

Just overwrite it with the path to your css file in the constants section of your root template like this:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.cssFile = path/to/file.css
```

Or remove the whole css file output by adding that instead:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.cssFile >
```

Comment: In the new version of news, in...list.html there is no plugin.tx_news but i can add one.
In the mainTemplate i have added this code.
#News Plugin Extension Setup.
plugin.tx_news {
        view {
                templateRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Templates/
                partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Partials/
                layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Layouts/
        }
}

Comment: Hi again...adding plugin.tx_news.settings.cssFile > after my code in TS, did the work, so thx for ur guidings...